# Vue-Multiselect, setting options based on fetched data

Tags: vue.js, frontend

Using the following library https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/tree/next for implementing a multiselect dropdown for my project.

I am calling my backend like so to retrieve the data. Assume that `clientOptions` by default is set like this in the data section of my vue file: `clientOptions: []`

```
 async fetchClients() {
  try {
    const clients = await clientService.getAllClients();
    this.clientOptions = clients.map((client) => ({
      name: client.name,
      id: client.id,
    }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching clients", error);
  }
```

I am attempting to display `clientOptions` like so:

```
<VueMultiselect
  v-model="selectedClients"
  :options="clientOptions"
  :searchable="true"
  :close-on-select="false"
  :allow-empty="false"
  track-by="name"
/>
```

However, what is happening is that it is displaying the entire array of each object (name and id). I would want it so that it just displays the name property of each object.

Comment: you're missing the `label` prop per the [documentation](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-single-select-object), e.g. `label="name"`